# How to break the input xml into token and read the token values

Tags: xslt-2.0

Below is the input to the xslt

```
<docValues>
01|1596056|CCCCCCCCCDD|028571|ABCCHAS|29150699|150800|FFSSSSFFFF|005| |N|N|002| | |0000020319|29150699|163000|29150699|153100|666666|20140627|400|RRRRR|400| |20150701
02|1596056|028571|29150699|0001|400| | |0001|THIS IS MY SERVICE,,| | | |0901.99| |0.5| 
03|1596056|028571|29150699|0001|5103|29150699|29150699| |1.000|99.098| | 
<docValues>

Below are the details of xml input
    01 : First Line Number
    02 : Second Line Number
    03 : Third Line Number
```

XSLT should read input xml and outout below xml

```
<SO>
    <line01_2nd_token>1596056</line01_2nd_token>
    <line01_4th_token>028571</line01_4th_token>
    <line01_5th_token>ABCCHAS</line01_4th_token>
<SO>
<PARIS>
    <line01_4th_token>028571</line01_4th_token>
    <line02_5th_token>0001</line02_5th_token>
    <line03_11th_token>99.098</line03_11th_token>
</PARIS>
<MY_SERVICE>
    <line01_4th_token>028571</line01_4th_token>
    <line03_5th_token>0001</line02_5th_token>
    <line02_6th_token>400</line02_6th_token>
</MY_SERVICE>
```

To achieve above output : the lines(01,02,03) in input xml needs to be break into tokens with | as delimiter, so that i can read the desired token value in the respective lines (01,02,03)

So here my question is how to break the input xml into token and read the token values.

Is there any way to achieve the desired output

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a function `tokenize` you could use twice, first with the second argument `'\r?\n'` to find the lines, then you can tokenize each line on `'\|'`.

Here is an example extracting some tokens, you should be able to complete that on your own:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="docValues">
        <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(., '\r?\n')[normalize-space()]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="line1-tokens" select="tokenize($lines[1], '\|')"/>
        <SO>
            <line01_2nd_token><xsl:value-of select="$line1-tokens[2]"/></line01_2nd_token>
        </SO>
        <PARIS>
            <line01_4th_token><xsl:value-of select="$line1-tokens[4]"/></line01_4th_token>
        </PARIS>
        <MY_SERVICE>
            <line01_4th_token><xsl:value-of select="$line1-tokens[4]"/></line01_4th_token>
        </MY_SERVICE>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the information but i am failing to achieve the desired output. can you please help me out from where i can start and how to navigate to next/previous line. once the line is broken into token how can i directly read the desired token value